# when does schur convex function imply weak majorization

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, majorization

I am studying about majorization and Schur convexity. And would appreciate a help.

Assume that you have a two vectors say $x,y \in R^d$, further assume that we have a Schur Convex function $\phi(x)$, we know that if $y$ weakly majorizes $x$ then $\phi(x)\leq \phi(y)$.
Is  there any result that we have the above hold for on the other way around, i.e., if and only if.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector $y$ weakly majorizes a vector $x$ *if and only if* $\sum_{i=1}^d h(y_i)\geq \sum_{i=1}^d h(x_i)$ for every (continuous) convex function $h: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to read more about this particular issue, do you know where I can find this as a theory? e.g., a book name, website or survey paper etc.
Thanks

Comment: Try Arnold, *Majorization and the Lorenz Order: A Brief Introduction", Springer, 1987 or Marshall and Olin, *Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications", Academic Press, 1979.

Comment: In page 12 of "Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications" (2011 Ed.), it said that y weakly majorizes x if and only if $\sum h(y_i) \ge \sum h(x_i)$ for all continuous **increasing** convex functions $h: R\to R$.